# Magento:: What is the difference between soap API version 1 and 2?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

What is the difference between magento SOAP API version 1 & 2, For our websites we accessing magento api, We have tried both version, but the results are strange. its giving entirely different results, one is order items inclusive tax and other is exclusive tax

Pleas check the below urls

**SOAP V2**

http://siterevista.com/allsites/nespresso_apis/salesOrderInvoiceInfoV2.php

```
$result = $client->salesOrderInvoiceInfo ($session, $invoice_id);
```

**SOAP V1**

http://siterevista.com/allsites/nespresso_apis/salesOrderInvoiceInfo.php

```
$result = $client->call($session, 'sales_order_invoice.info', $invoice_id);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html

Comment: I saw that but what makes difference in results? As your opinion  Should use v1 ?

Answer (score 2):

V2 has a WSDL section for each method called. V2 only has sections for a few general methods.
In the case of V1 all data from the invoice object is returned. This means you get all the fields in the `sales_flat_invoice` table.
For V2 you get only the fields specified in the WSDL for the call response type (not necessarily all the fields).
Check `app/code/code/Mage/Sales/etc/wsdl.xml` (or `wsi.xml`) and look for this type:
`<complexType name="salesOrderInvoiceEntity">` to see how it looks.

Comment: Any idea what is the idea behind less data pulling from db?

Comment: @duke not sure what you mean

Comment: sorry for my english. what I meant is why they are showing less details in V2 ,is it related to performance  issue?

Comment: @duke. I don't know the reason behind this. Most probably V2 returns only some information that is really needed. If you need more you can extend the API. See here a tutorial on how to do it: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/1331/146. It's for extending the product wsdl section but it works the same for other entities.